# Using Dashes with a Possessive

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, possessives, dashes

If you have a possessive proper noun but want to add extra detail by using dashes, how should it be written?

**Example:**

> Penny - our neighbour - has blonde hair.

Would any of these options be correct?

> 1. Penny's - our neighbour - hair is blonde.
> 2. Penny - our neighbour's - hair is blonde.
> 3. Penny's - our neighbour's - hair is blonde.

I know it's not an ideal construction, but I'd still like to know.

Comment: None of those options is remotely idiomatic English as I know it.  AFAICS, if you're going to use the possessive, you have to forgo the parenthetic comment (even if the parenthetic remark is marked by dashes instead of brackets/parentheses).  "Our neighbour Penny's hair is blonde" works for me, but isn't wholly comfortable.

Comment: In speech, I think *Penny—our neighbor—her hair is blond* might be just as likely as any of the constructions above. But I would avoid all of them in writing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (English is a very personal language) your initial thought "Penny - our neighbour - has blonde hair." is to be preferred.  I would avoid the three alternatives you give; they seem to me to be ugly and difficult to parse. If I were writing this, I'd use commas rather than dashes - it's more conventional.